# SP for inserting data from an existing table to a new table

Tags: sql

I have a database which has a table like this:

```
Serial Id EmpId Name Date(datetime) in_out(nvarchar(50))
```

This is the master table.
I need a stored procedure which will fetch the data from this table.
And it'll also insert that data in the following table which is as below:

```
Serial Id EmpId Name, InTime(time), OutTime(time), Date(Date)
```

Now I need a Stored Procedure which will fetch the data from the first table and will process the data and will insert the data in the second table.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try with following example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [schema_name].[procedure_name]
AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO tblChild (Col1, Col2, Col3)
(SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM tblMaster)
END
```